# Markers don't appear on my google map api v2 ( Blank Acitivity )

Tags: android, api, android-studio

Am using google map api v2 , first i tryed it on a google map acitivy it works fine , then i tryed on a blank activity but markers dont appear when i add them and am not getting localised help pls

that's my main activity code

```
package pixel.lastmaptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
            .title("It Works !"));
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the MapFragment in XML ? If yes there should be some log about the error why map is not inflating (i.e. Blank Activity).

Also, You need to call getMapAsync() to get the callback in onMapReady().

Comment: Hi thats my xml fil
`<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>`

and i havent understood how to call getMapAsync() to get the callback in onMapReady().   

thanks for helping

Comment: For above layout, map should be visible..
To get map object and call getMapAsync() do this :: 
`MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this code, you have not created a map yet.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html)

> Once an instance of this interface is set on a MapFragment or MapView object, the onMapReady(GoogleMap) method is triggered when the map is ready to be used and provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap.

You can create a MapFragment in your XML:

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Or programatically:

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(MapActivity.this);
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frmMain, mMapFragment, "fragmentMap");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Hi i already have this i just forget to post it 
`<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>`